# Meaning of the sentence : 「成すべきことを成す」

Tags: translation, expressions, idioms

I came across this sentence in a manga and its meaning is rather obscure to me:

> 成すべきことを成す。

I tried to translate it as:

> To do what has to be done.

Moreover, it would be great to know if this sentence is a common idiom or just a normal sentence that anybody could spontaneously come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation is correct.

The sentence is not an idiom because the meaning is exactly what it says. An idiom is when the meaning of the expression is different from the meaning of the individual words.

It seems to be quite common. I searched the net and Google gives me 6,220 results.

Comment: Google says "about 6220 results", but actually only has 136 results without repeats and 441 results with repeats. (At least this time it's not [off by more than nine orders of magnitude](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/522/google-counts-may-not-be-as-reliable-as-you-imagine), only one and a bit...)